# SELECT with Limit in SQL messing up order of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get some rows from SQL and order them by ID. Currently my query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id ASC;
```

This will get all my rows and print them vertically in ascending order of id:

```
1
2
3
4 etc etc.
```

Now, the problem is I would like only the bottom 2 to be printed, like this:

```
3
4
```

But I have tried different pieces of code and it won't work. To give you an example, I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id ASC DESC limit 10
```

But this will print this, so the order is wrong again!

```
4
3
```

Any ideas? Thanks guys

Comment: You're also using `ASC DESC` instead of just either `ASC` or `DESC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM logs 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT 2
) subquery 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Please note that selecting from subqueries requires an alias (in this case `subquery`). Otherwise you'll get error `Every derived table must have its own alias`, at least in MySQL.

Comment: Daniel that was a mistype. Thanks Mateusz that was great